# R- How do I compare percentages calculated from a subset of categorical variables?

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to show that one percentage is significantly greater than another, and I am trying to perform the t-test for that, would that be correct? How would I do that in R?

```
FreqAinCond1 = sum(Cond1$Form=="A")/nrow(Cond1)
FreqAinCond2 = sum(Cond2$Form=="A")/nrow(Con2)
```

I gathered my percentages as above, where Cond1 and Cond2 are subsets of a larger dataset, I am trying to find the proportion of the occurrences of A out of all of the responses in both conditions. Ultimately, I am showing that the proportion of A is significantly larger than that in Cond2. How would I perform a t-test with these two numbers? I tried saving them in a data frame, didn't work.

```
Conditions<-c("Cond1","Cond2")
Freq<-c(FreqAinCond1,FreqAinCond2)
t.test(Conditions~Freq,mu=0,alt="two-sided",conf=0.95,var.eq=F,paired=F)
```

I tried using prop.table, didn't work either.

```
prop.test(FreqAinCond1,FreqAinCond2)
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I even using the right test? Thanks!

Comment: you're using `prop.test(prop1, prop2)`--that's not how `prop.test` is used

Comment: How would I run a t-test on FreqAinCon1 and FreqAinCond2 though?

Comment: `prop.test` would be the obvious way to go. Check the arguments for `x` and `n`